# bing maps ajax control - pass vb.net textbox location to javascript

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, asp.net-ajax, bing-maps

I am trying to dynamically generate a bing maps map from a number of UK postcodes. Although examples with hard coded locations are available I am struggling with finding an example showing how a postcode could be entered into a asp.net (VB) text box (or 5 boxes actually) and once a button is clicked those variables will be passed to the bing map and displayed (unfortuantley my Javascript is not very good)

I have been using the "Interactive SDk" and this example is close to what I want: http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#Pushpins5

Does anyone know how to adapt this so I can pass the values of several textboxes to show several pushpins on the map?

Thanks in advance

James

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, why do they need to be server side textbox?

Their json result request can handle just about any query you can throw at it. Simply concatenate your text boxes into a search query separated by commas.

```
function callSearchService(credentials) {
    var searchString =document.getElementById('txtStreetNum').value + ' ' +  document.getElementById('txtQueryStr').value + ' , ' + document.getElementById('txtQueryCity').value + ' , ' + document.getElementById('txtQueryState').value + ' , ' + document.getElementById('txtQueryPostal').value;
    var geocodeRequest = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=" + encodeURI(searchString) + "&output=json&jsonp=searchServiceCallback&key=" + credentials;
}
```

If for some reason, you really need to get the text from an asp.net text control (Maybe you want to pre-load it for a user), you can do it like this;

```
var aspTextBoxValue = '<%=ASPTextBox.Text%>';
```

To make it add different pushpins for different query box's you will need to do a few things:

1. Concatenate separate searchStrings per query (`callSearchService` for each query)
2. Make geocodeRequests for each query.
3. Parse each result object and display the pushpin as seen in `searchServiceCallback` in the following example:

(Your example doesnt actually resemble and query / response parsing at all, here's one more suitable)

[Query and Response in Bing Maps](http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#RESTServices1)

Don't expect my syntax to be perfect, although it may be error free,  I'm just getting you off on the right foot without doing it for you. :)